# How can I acces drag-and-drop buttons by String in a loop?

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a desktop application which includes graphic scheme and that scheme has 50 drag-and-drop buttons(they are not dynamically allocated) they are all named similar(for example button 1 is btnP1, button 2 is btnP2 etc...). I would like to access those buttons with a for loop  using string, I checked some previous posts on this site but none of those answers helped my problem.

I wrote 50 lines of codes to add those buttons to controls, and the same moment I add them to the controls they disappear from the graphic scheme. Later I tried to access them through for loop, but nothing happened, since they disappear once I add them to the controls..

```
        this.Controls.Add(btnP1);
        this.Controls.Add(btnP2);
        this.Controls.Add(btnP3);
        this.Controls.Add(btnP4);
        ... and so on
        this.Controls.Add(btnP47);
        this.Controls.Add(btnP48);
        this.Controls.Add(btnP49);
        this.Controls.Add(btnP50);

for(int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
{
this.Controls["btnP"+ i.ToString()].Visible= False;
}
```

I would like to find out if there is some other way to access my buttons, because I need them to be shown and hidden.

Comment: try to acces them with a simple `foreach()` loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To loop over all buttons within one control you can use a `foreach` loop

```
foreach(Button btn in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
   btn.Visible = false; //every button in you Control
}
```

With this code lines you run through the entire `Control`.

With the `OfType` method you filter only the buttons out of the control. So you prevent an `InvalidCastException` error.

[Enumerable.OfType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @AhmetHalilović If it worked please upvote the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Mario's answer but I would probably expand the selectors if their naming is consistent and filter out ones that can't be dropped:

```
        foreach (Button btn in this.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("btnP") && x.AllowDrop))
        {
            btn.Visible = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ version:

```
this.Controls
.OfType<Button>()
.Where(b => b.Name.StartsWith("btnP") && b.AllowDrop)
.ToList()
.ForEach(b => b.Visible = false);
```